# How to include only specific files from the main/java to be part of jar to be published to using gradle?

Tags: gradle, jar, build.gradle, maven-publish

I don't want the whole `main/java` to be pushed as Jar

Instead, I want only specific folders inside `main/java` to be part of the jar.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this part of your `build.gradle` has nothing to do with creating the JAR file. It just defines a publication that refers to the Java component built by your Java project. One part of this Java project is the task `jar`, which actually creates the JAR file. This task is of type [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html), so it offers methods to either `exclude` files following a pattern or to only include files following a pattern:

```
jar {
    include '**/path/to/included/files/*.class'
    // alternatively
    exclude '**/path/to/excluded/files/*.class'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Lukas
Since, I didn't see any `jar` task in the build.gradle, I thought `from components.java` is responsible for the same. But really thanks for the clarification. Used it and it is working flawlesslly :)